# Using python/BeautifulSoup to replace HTML tag pair with a different one

Tags: python, html, replace, tags, beautifulsoup

I need to replace a matching pair of HTML tags by another tag. Probably BeautifulSoup (4) would be suitable for the task, but I've never used it before and haven't found a suitable example anywhere, can someone give me a hint?

For example, this HTML code:

```
<font color="red">this text is red</font>
```

Should be changed to this:

```
<span style="color: red;">this text is red</span>
```

The beginning and ending HTML tags may not be in the same line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`replace_with()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) to replace elements. Adapting the documentation example to your example gives:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> markup = '<font color="red">this text is red</font>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
>>> soup.font
<font color="red">this text is red</font>
>>> new_tag = soup.new_tag('span')
>>> new_tag['style'] = 'color: ' + soup.font['color']
>>> new_tag.string = soup.font.string
>>> soup.font.replace_with(new_tag)
<font color="red">this text is red</font>
>>> soup
<span style="color: red">this text is red</span>
```