# Beautifulsoup add/insert html tag line in xml document

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to add a line with HTML  tag using beautifulsoup.

Input:

```
<tr>
    <td>Hi </td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>World</td>
</tr>
```

Output:I want to add the 4th line which is Good Morning in seperate  tag

```
<tr>
    <td>Hi </td>
    <td>Hello</td>
<!--<td>World</br>Good Morning</td> -->
    <td></br>Good Morning</td> 

</tr>
```

I made the comment using replacewith function, now i'm stuck with adding new line. please help me on this.

Comment: So you want `world` to be replaced by `</br>Good Morning` this right?

Comment: yes ,is there anyway to do it , please help me on this

Comment: Try researching and writing some code yourself before asking for help. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356014/how-can-i-insert-a-new-tag-into-a-beautifulsoup-object) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598524/can-i-remove-script-tags-with-beautifulsoup) post to start.

Comment: @Joseph , I tried many ways like insert , insert_after but most of them are at soup level and the examples are one line but the above code which td at nested level i didnt find good example..FYI i was trying from past 2 hours

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using python/BeautifulSoup to replace HTML tag pair with a different one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545594/using-python-beautifulsoup-to-replace-html-tag-pair-with-a-different-one)

Comment: No Tijmen , I want to change the text within html tag

Answer (score 1):

First find the element and then `next_element` which is text and then replace with your text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<tr>
    <td>Hi </td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>World</td>
</tr>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
soup.find('td',text='World').next_element.replace_with("</br>Good Morning")
print(soup.prettify(formatter=None))
```

**Output**:

```
<tr>
 <td>
  Hi
 </td>
 <td>
  Hello
 </td>
 <td>
  </br>Good Morning
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , actually i have xml document within it i have small part of above code.i read it as lxml document now i guess i cant read it as htmll parser

Comment: @mukeshtech01 : does this solution helps to problem?